# How would you make a section for Your Orders

Tags: sql, database, e-commerce

I'm looking to create a section on my eCommerce site that shows the consumers past orders. Would this have to be done by creating a new table for each customer or is there any better / more easier way of doing it?

Comment: What is your current structure ?

Comment: What do you mean by structure? My Databases? I have a table for members and a table for products.

Comment: Well, it would make sense to create customers, customerOrder, customerOrderLine tables

Comment: would you be able to help me with that? Please send me your email.

Comment: yes I am, could you please email me?

Comment: fkhalikov(at sign)gmail.com is my email.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple schema to accommodate your data using MySQL, script is also available in here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4aa3

```
CREATE TABLE tblCustomers
(
   CustomerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  ,CustomerName VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE tblCustomerOrder
(
    OrderID INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY
  , CustomerID INT
  , OrderDate DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE tblCustomerOrderLines
(
    OrderID INT
  , ProductID INT
  , Quantity INT
  , LineAmount FLOAT
);
```

For SQL Server 2008:

```
CREATE TABLE tblCustomers
(
   CustomerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ,CustomerName VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE tblCustomerOrder
(
    OrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY
  , CustomerID INT
  , OrderDate DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE tblCustomerOrderLines
(
    OrderID INT
  , ProductID INT
  , Quantity INT
  , LineAmount DECIMAL(9,2)
);
```